# How to set an infinite session time out with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-security

I have a request from a client to stop sessions timing out (yes, I know this is a bad idea). The webapp is developed using Spring Security and will be hosted on Heroku. I know I can set a finite session timeout with:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

I'm hoping there's a parameter I can put here (-1 perhaps?) that will prevent the session timing out.

Comment: cant you just set ridiculously long time to timeout? Like a 1000 years? Or two, just to be sure

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-1` and the *session will not expire.*

```
 <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
```

Answer (score 2):

*Session invalidate because there is no communication between client-side and server side* so server don't know about the users state.

Here you need infinite session timeout so Use **-1** in `<session-timeout>` tag because `-1` is for **session never expires**

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

From Java side

```
request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
```